# Prevent off-screen div from moving on resizing

Tags: css

I have a drawer menu that appears on screen after clicking a button. The transition is a little laggy using absolute positioning so I went with using translate3d. The menu has two widths. One that's 100% of the view for mobile and 395px for viewports 600px and up. One quirk I'm noticing is that if I were to resize my screen, the menu will subtly appear. Is there a way to get the menu to completely stay off-screen when this happens?

**Note:** To see this, expand the snipped to full-screen and horizontally resize to 600px or lower. You should see see the div appear and go back off-screen.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#drawer').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#drawer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

#drawer.active {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #drawer {
    transform: translate3d(-395px, 0, 0);
    width: 395px;
  }
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawer"></div>

<button>Toggle Drawer</button>
```

Comment: it doesnt work at me

Comment: Your problem is the `transition` rule. When your viewport resizes, the new transform rule takes affect over .5s

Comment: I figured but what would be the best solution that would keep the transition intact?

Comment: @CarlEdwards perhaps disabling the style rule on window.resize via Javascript

Comment: True. Just hate to go the js route for something so small.

Comment: Setting the #drawer display to none, then on the media query setting the display back to block fixed this for me. Does that accomplish what you're looking for? Agree that js might be a bit much for these little issues

Comment: @JeremyLucas Wow so you were still able to get the transform transition to still work despite having the display property?

Comment: Now that I think of it I may to add the JS for the click event

Comment: My apologies, looks like the transition was disabled on that. I didn't catch that, just noticed that it wasn't having any issues with the resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:** A transition is set on the drawer's transform property. When it hits the designated media query, the drawer transitions to it's new x coordinate.

**The solution:** Instead of putting the responsibility of placement solely on transform, use absolute positioning and initially offset the drawer to its' negative width. In this case it would be 395px. On the active state, the transform3d property would be the width of the drawer to bring it back into the visible part of the window.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#drawer').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#drawer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#drawer.active {
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #drawer {
    left: -395px;
    width: 395px;
  }
  
  #drawer.active {
    transform: translate3d(395px, 0, 0);
  }
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawer"></div>

<button>Toggle Drawer</button>
```